# embeding Invision prototype

Tags: html, css, iframe, embed

They gave me this code

`<iframe width="424" height="916" src="//invis.io/U5574OIA3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

but I'm not sure how to actually embed it? I tried inserting that line to my website but nothing shows up.

I will provide more info if necessary. Thanks in advance

update:

```
   <div class="container">
<div class="row project">
<div class="ten columns offset-by-one">
  <h class="pageheadproject">Final Outcome</h>
  <p class="divider">~</p>

  <p class="subheadproject">User Scenario</p>
  <p class="pagecontent2-first"> Sample Text </p>

  <iframe width="424" height="916" src="//invis.io/U5574OIA3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

I gave the iframe a border and now it looks like this [image]

Answer (score 1):

yes you should maybe precise the way you embed it in your website as it seems to work in this simple [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/smlrolland/vtjajdxv/)

```
<iframe width="424" height="916" src="//invis.io/U5574OIA3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: That's really weird because I can't see anything on my website :/ il update my html above

Comment: What was your problem then ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was but I just added a text in between and it worked. <iframe width="424" height="916" src="http://invis.io/U5574OIA3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
      </iframe>